# R: BDP with overrides problems

Tags: r, overriding, bloomberg

I am trying to replicate the following Bloomberg function in R:
BDP("000361AQ8 CUSIP","TOT_DEBT_TO_EBITDA","EQY_FUND_YEAR","2013","FUND_PER","q2")

So far I have been able to create the following, however, all my outputs produce NAs:

```
require(Rbbg)
conn <- blpConnect(throw.ticker.errors = F)
fields <- c("TOT_DEBT_TO_EBITDA")
overrides_fields <- c("EQY_FUND_YEAR","FUND_PER")
overrides <- c("2013","q2")

data <- bdp(conn,"000361AQ8 CUSIP",fields,overrides_fields,overrides)
```

Answer (score 0):

000361AQ8 CUSIP should be 000361AQ8 Corp.

If 000361AQ8 CUSIP ever worked for you, keep in mind that the Terminal is least strict about input formats, BDP is more strict, and other API implementations are stricter. Server API is least forgiving - for example, it doesn't parse source overrides in the ticker field the way BDP does (e.g. 000361AQ8 BXSU Corp PX_LAST)

You should use the most correct "Yellow Key" sector for the symbol you want.

There is even an API field to get the correct "Yellow Key" market sector to use with a symbol, once you have identified it by any tolerated method.